# Mock HTTP Call Out In Test to Return XML

Tags: apex, xml, httpcalloutmock

I am very new to HTTP Callouts and now I am in the testing phase. My HTTP Callout returns XML

This is the link. I input a company already, soulcycle, in case anybody wanted to see what was being returned from the HTTP Request.

https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=soulcycle&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en

Anyways, here is my Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class getRSSFeed {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Map<String,String>> getCompanyRSSFeed(String url, String recordID) {

    String recordName = getRecordName(recordID);

    List<Map<String,String>> newsArticles = search(url, recordName);

    return newsArticles;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String getRecordName(String recordID)
{
    String accountRecordID = recordID;
    return [SELECT Name From Account WHERE ID = : accountRecordID limit 1].Name;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static  List<Map<String,String>> search(String remoteSiteURL, String query)
{
    String url = remoteSiteURL + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query, 'UTF-8');

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

    while (res.getStatusCode() == 302) {
        req.setEndpoint(res.getHeader('Location'));
        System.debug(res.getHeader('Location'));
        res = new Http().send(req);
    }

    Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
    Dom.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();

    Dom.XMLNode bodyNode = root.getChildElement('channel', null);

    //Dom.XMLNode bodyNode = bodyNode.getChildElement('');
    List<Map<String,String>> newsStories = new List<Map<String,String>>();
    Integer sizeOfList = 20;
    Integer i = 0;


    for(DOM.XmlNode x : bodyNode.getChildren())
    {
        //System.debug(x.getName());
        //System.debug(x.getText());
        if(x.getName() == 'item' &&
            i != sizeOfList)
        {
            Map<String,String> story = new Map<String, String>();
            story.put('publisher', '');
            story.put('date', '');
            story.put('link', '');
            story.put('image', '');
            story.put('title', '');
            story.put('description', '');


            for(DOM.XmlNode itemChildren : x.getChildElements())
            {
                System.debug(itemChildren.getName());

                //System.debug(itemChildren.getName());
                //System.debug(itemChildren.getText());
                if(itemChildren.getName() == 'link')
                {
                    story.put('link', itemChildren.getText());
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'title')
                {
                    story.put('title', itemChildren.getText());
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'pubDate')
                {
                    story.put('date', itemChildren.getText());
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'description')
                {

                    String stripTags = itemChildren.getText();
                    List<String> description = stripTags.split('(<.*?>)');
                    story.put('description', description[5]);
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'content')
                {
                    story.put('image', itemChildren.getAttributeValue(itemChildren.getAttributeKeyAt(0), itemChildren.getAttributeKeyNsAt(0)));
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'source')
                {
                    story.put('publisher', itemChildren.getText());
                }


            }

            newsStories.add(story);
            i += 1;

        }

    }
    return newsStories;
}
```

}

Here is my Test Class (Which is honestly embarrassing right now, because I have no clue what I am doing.)

```
public with sharing class getRSSFeed {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Map<String,String>> getCompanyRSSFeed(String url, String recordID) {

    String recordName = getRecordName(recordID);

    List<Map<String,String>> newsArticles = search(url, recordName);

    return newsArticles;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String getRecordName(String recordID)
{
    String accountRecordID = recordID;
    return [SELECT Name From Account WHERE ID = : accountRecordID limit 1].Name;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static  List<Map<String,String>> search(String remoteSiteURL, String query)
{
    String url = remoteSiteURL + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query, 'UTF-8');

    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

    while (res.getStatusCode() == 302) {
        req.setEndpoint(res.getHeader('Location'));
        System.debug(res.getHeader('Location'));
        res = new Http().send(req);
    }

    Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument();
    Dom.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();

    Dom.XMLNode bodyNode = root.getChildElement('channel', null);

    //Dom.XMLNode bodyNode = bodyNode.getChildElement('');
    List<Map<String,String>> newsStories = new List<Map<String,String>>();
    Integer sizeOfList = 20;
    Integer i = 0;


    for(DOM.XmlNode x : bodyNode.getChildren())
    {
        //System.debug(x.getName());
        //System.debug(x.getText());
        if(x.getName() == 'item' &&
            i != sizeOfList)
        {
            Map<String,String> story = new Map<String, String>();
            story.put('publisher', '');
            story.put('date', '');
            story.put('link', '');
            story.put('image', '');
            story.put('title', '');
            story.put('description', '');


            for(DOM.XmlNode itemChildren : x.getChildElements())
            {
                System.debug(itemChildren.getName());

                //System.debug(itemChildren.getName());
                //System.debug(itemChildren.getText());
                if(itemChildren.getName() == 'link')
                {
                    story.put('link', itemChildren.getText());
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'title')
                {
                    story.put('title', itemChildren.getText());
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'pubDate')
                {
                    story.put('date', itemChildren.getText());
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'description')
                {

                    String stripTags = itemChildren.getText();
                    List<String> description = stripTags.split('(<.*?>)');
                    story.put('description', description[5]);
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'content')
                {
                    story.put('image', itemChildren.getAttributeValue(itemChildren.getAttributeKeyAt(0), itemChildren.getAttributeKeyNsAt(0)));
                }
                else if(itemChildren.getName() == 'source')
                {
                    story.put('publisher', itemChildren.getText());
                }


            }

            newsStories.add(story);
            i += 1;

        }

    }
    return newsStories;
}
```

}

I know this test class is really bad. I am researching a lot on how to achieve 100% code coverage. If you have any tips, please send them over. I appreciate all the help I can get!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you may have copy/pasted your real class twice (instead of including your test class). You can fix that by making an [edit]. Also, to format your code correctly, the easiest way is probably to paste your code in the editor window, highlight it, and then click the `{}` button (or press `ctrl` + `k` on windows, `cmd` + `k` on mac)

Comment: Also, if you haven't read it already, [Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) should get you part of the way to knowing what you need to do in your test.

Comment: Hi Matthew, welcome to SFSE. Right now I don't see a [specific question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the body of your post, which our format looks for. If you're looking for general help with unit testing, please see our [canonical QA](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa) section, which has extensive resources. Otherwise, could you make an [edit] to clarify what you need (and, as Derek said, include the actual test class)?